# Stuck at converting application/x-www-form-urlencoded to JSON using reduce function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` values into JSON using `reduce`.

```
const params = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4'

const json = params.split('&').reduce((result, item) => {
   const parts = item.split('=')
   result = result || {}
   result[parts[0]] = parts[1]
   return result
   
});
```

But it does not work.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you omit the second argument to reduce, it defaults to the first item, not to undefined as you seem to think. So

```js
const params = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4'

const json = params.split('&').reduce((result, item) => {
   const parts = item.split('=')
   result[parts[0]] = parts[1]
   return result
}, {}); // <--- here

console.log(json)
```

Also note that there's a simpler way to do the same:

```
result = Object.fromEntries(
    params.split('&').map(p => p.split('='))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add initial value `{}`

```js
const params = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4'

const json = params.split('&').reduce((result, item) => {
  const parts = item.split('=')
  result = result || {}
  result[parts[0]] = parts[1]
  return result

}, {});

console.log(json)
```

Side note: You are creating an object, not a json.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) expects [two arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters): the callback function and the initial value.

When the initial value is not provided, it uses the first item of the array as the initial value on the first call of the callback. This does not match your expectations to get `undefined` in `results` on the first call.

The solution is to call it correctly, with two arguments:

```js
const params = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4'

const object = params.split('&').reduce(
  (result, item) => {
    const parts = item.split('=')
    result[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    return result
  },
  {}
);
console.log(object);
```

Btw, a [JSON](https://json.org) is a string, a text representation of some data structure. JSON is not involved in any way in this question. The code builds a JavaScript plain object. You can pass this object to [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to encode it as JSON but that is a different thing and is not related to this question.